# Background of long OP username looks ugly in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comments

I just noticed something funny in the comments to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167888/i-set-a-campfire-on-fire):

[image: Screenshot]

See the messy "scratches" on each end of the OP's username?  I'm pretty sure they're not supposed to be there.

The reason this happens is because the same CSS class, `owner`, is used to style both the OP's username in the comments and the fancy box containing the OP's user card below the question.  The "mess" in the comment username is simply a small slice of the background image intended for the user card:

[image: Background]

A simple CSS fix would be to disable the background image for comments, like this:

```
a.comment-user.owner {
    background-image: none;
}
```

This will eliminate the messy background image, but will leave the solid background color in place.

---

Ps. Ugh, I just noticed that the code block above looks really ugly, because the background color for `<code>` tags here on meta.ELU is set to `#e0e0e0`, while that of the surrounding `<pre>` block is `#eee` (which is shorthand for `#eeeeee`).  It doesn't seem to happen on the main site, where both have a background color of `#eee`.  This could be fixed either by making the colors match, or by adding an extra rule to remove the background entirely from `<code>` inside `<pre>`, like this:

```
pre code {
    background: transparent;
}
```

---

Pps. Both of the CSS fixes above are now included in the [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.14 user script.

Comment: Ahah! I was wondering what was actually going on there. Thanks for sleuthing it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer true. The problem has since been fixed.

Comment: Ahh, "status completed" tag. Hadn't noticed that, so why is the post still open?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Because resolved bug reports aren't traditionally closed, and also because there's no standard close reason for it on per-site metas. (There *is* a "no longer reproducible" close reason on meta.SE and meta.SO which sometimes gets used, if the mods forget to add the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag.) I suppose I should self-answer this and accept it, just so it won't get bumped by Community ♦ later.

Comment: Retracted close vote. Thank you for answering so swiftly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that both of these issues have been fixed at some point, probably as a side effect of the general SE design rework carried out in spring.  Owner comments now have a solid-color background, and the background color of `<pre>` and `<code>` tags is now consistently `#eee`.