# Background of OP username looks ugly in comments

Tags: bug, design, comments

Firefox 36.0, Windows 7 SP 1 x64, the name of the OP looks strange:

[image: Screenshot]

This has already been [reported before](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/background-of-long-op-username-looks-ugly-in-comments), but since that question was asked almost a year ago, I guess it was already fixed and now reappears.

Comment: Does not apply to meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now along with a handful of other bugs.

Comment: Thanks for working on it.